# import variables from another file to function in python

Tags: python, function, variables

**variables.py**

```
path="c:/something"
path2="c:/somethng2"
path3="c:/something3"
....
```

**main.py**

```
def run():
    from variables import *

...
```

**i have such error:**

> SyntaxError: import * is not allowed in function 'run' because it contains a nested function with free variables

Comment: `import variables` than use `variables.path, variables.path2,....`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import variables as v
path=v.path
```

This should do for path variable from other file
Hope this helps!

Comment: if i did mypath1=variables.mypath1 unfortunately i still have such error: NameError: global name variables is not defined

Comment: may be you are still doing from `variables import *` the following is working for me `import variables
path=variables.path
print path`

Comment: Why don't you just do the import at the top itself

Comment: thanks. it helped. anyway global variables sucks in python :)

Answer (score 1):

You should be very careful with global variables. It is considered a better practice to avoid using global variables, updating them in different locations in the code. It should not be a problem if those are only constants, though. Usually I do it this way:

**variables.py**:

```
MY_PATH1 ="c:/something"
MY_PATH2 ="c:/somethng2"
MY_PATH3 ="c:/something3"
```

**main.py**

```
from variables import *

def run():
    print(MY_PATH1)
    ...
```

If you are working with path strings, you may also want to take a look in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html) for the `os.path` module. It helps making path descriptors compatible with the different platforms, among other useful things.